# Does Go support templates or generics?

Tags: oop, generics, go

I know that Go doesn't have classes in the traditional OOP sense, but Go does provide a notion of interfaces that allows you do most of the OOP things you'd want to do.

BUT, does Go allow for something like creating a templated class? For instance, I'm reading through the source code for the container/list package. It defines a list and the list's associated methods. But in all methods, the values contained in the list are of type `interface{}` -- so, of any type. Is there any way to create a list that is constrained to only hold values of a *particular* type? int, string, Fruit... whatever.

Comment: Sorry, Go does not support generics or templates. Such things might appear in Go 2 though.

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/faq#generics

Comment: Also found this pertinent thread in the golang group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/6GF80NwGD6c/discussion

Answer (score 5):

Newer than gotgo, there's a code-generation-based package called "gen".

http://clipperhouse.github.io/gen/

> gen is an attempt to bring some generics-like functionality to Go, with inspiration from C#’s Linq, JavaScript’s Array methods and the underscore library. Operations include filtering, grouping, sorting and more.
>
> The pattern is to pass func’s as you would pass lambdas in Linq or functions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what [@FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuzxxl) said.

Generics? [Not at this time](http://golang.org/doc/faq#generics).

Templates? Not quite. There are third-party projects like [gotgo](https://github.com/droundy/gotgo) which aim to add template
support by pre-processing files. However, gotgo is quite dead as far as I know.

Your best option is to use interfaces or reflection for the time being.

If you really want to use reflection, note that the `reflect` package offers a way to [fill a typed function variable with generic (reflected) content](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeFunc). You can use this to use types the compiler
can check with your reflection based solutions.